# Is it good practice to include heavy logic in the constructor if it guarantees immutability?

Tags: java, oop

From my understanding, it's good practice to make objects immutable where-ever possible. Does this mean adding heavy constructor logic is preferred in cases where it achieves immutability? I have an example below.

Mutable:

```
public class Database {
  
  private List<String> database;
  private String path;
  
  public Database(String path) {
    this.path = path;
    database = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void parseAndLoad() {
    // heavy logic to parse the file and load into the database
  }

}
```

Immutable:

```
public class Database {

  private List<String> database;
  private String path;
  
  public Database(String path) {
    this.path = path;
    database = new ArrayList<>();
    parseAndLoad(); // load the database in the constructor
  }

  private void parseAndLoad() {
    // heavy logic to parse the file and load into the database
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense in how to use it if you put the code in a static factory method.

Example: Which of these better helps the programmer read and understand the code?

```java
// Using constructor
Database db = new Database("/path/to/Customers.db");

// Using static method
Database db = Database.parseAndLoad("/path/to/Customers.db");
```

To me, the first one looks like it might create a new database, potentially replacing an existing database file. The second makes it obvious that it loads an existing database file into memory.

So, do this:

```java
public class Database {

  private String path;
  private List<String> database;

  public static Database parseAndLoad(String path) {
    List<String> database = new ArrayList<>();
    // heavy logic to parse the file and load into the database
    return new Database(path, database);
  }

  private Database(String path, List<String> database) { // Notice it's private
    this.path = path;
    this.database = database;
  }

}
```

You might even eliminate the `path` field, if it isn't needed after the load completes. Or keep it, e.g. if needed by a `save()` method and/or a `getPath()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on that's purpose. Absolutely if your heavy process does not depend on time or everything that makes your method output different for some particular requests or method callings. You have to do that to prevent do a same process several times. Also as you wrote in your examples it may be never called, which makes a bug.